# Angular : Updating property of passed object in child component updates parent component, updating its value doesn't, why?

Tags: angular, data-binding

There's a behavior in Angular I don't really understand. Let's say I've two components : a parent and a child. The parent component passes data to the child.

In the child component :

- When properties of the passed object are updated, the object updates **both in parent and child component**.
- When the object value is updated, the **parent component does not update**.

---

I don't know if I made it clear, so I made this **plunker** :

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/PnlotZxt3DLbAGAF?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview

Hit "Update Salary" to update the salary property of the employee object.
Hit "Update Employee" to update the employee object value.

Can someone please explain me this behavior ? I though using bracket and @Input() was for one-way data binding only and now I'm confused.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its matter of reference of Object. The changes can be detect as long as object are has the same reference.

In your case - You are assigning the new value to `employee` in child component which breaks the chain. Now the Parent is pointing to different `employee` object and child is referring to different `employee`.

In short you always need to make sure that you can change the property of object but should not reassign ( reference change ) to other object.

In your example I had modified the change from

```
this.employee = this.employee2;
```

to

```
Object.assign(this.employee,this.employee2);  // this will change the existing object.
```

Comment: @Paul - Feel free to mark the answer as accepted (with the green check mark) if it solved your problem.